# FullText mysql search AND neo4j search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, neo4j

I'm using two kind of databases in my project, mysql and neo4j. Content in mysql, relationship in neo4j.

My question is: (Take blog as an example)

1, If i use neo4j to do fulltext search, then i have to store **title** and **description** to neo4j DB and index these two column, is it ok to store huge content in neo4j DB?

2, How is the performance of mysql fulltext search? Compare to neo4j?

Comment: What do you mean by huge content ? How many titles and descriptions you will have ? From my experience, full-text search in Neo4j is quite fast, provided that you have enough memory and that the indexes are warm. It is also worth considering how this impacts the architecture of your application, as it is often harder to manage the data spread in two different data storages

Answer (score 1):

Graph databases are more suitable for storing huge data than any rdbms.
Performance of neo4j is far better than mysql for full text search as neo4j uses lucene.

if you want to use mysql any how then you can use lucene libaray and manage data in mysql.